# Laravel 5.2 Extending the Auth that comes with the scaffolding to use an additional table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am just learning to use Laravel and so far have set up a basic instance and then ran the php artisan make:auth command which setup the basic user registration etc.

What I want to do now is extend this auth to save an additional field from the registration in to a separate related table from Users called Titles.

I have managed to follow the user guide so far. This is where I am at just now:

In register.blade.php I have added in the additional field:

```
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Title</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Then in the AuthController.php I have added the title field to the validation:

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'title' => 'required|max:100',
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I then created a Title model and related it to the user:

```
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Title extends Model
 {
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }

  }
```

Then I updated the user model:

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function title()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Title');
}

 }
```

The migration for the Titles table looks like this so I think its correct:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('titles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 100);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is where I am sort of stuck now. How do I actually save the title field to the titles table and have it related to the user?

I see from the documentation that you use a format similar to:

```
$title = new Title(array('title' => 'test title'));

$title = $user->titles()->save($title);
```

But I am not sure how to apply it in this situation since the create function in the AuthController just returns a array right away.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Try 
`$user= User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

$title=new Title(['title' => 'A new title.']);

$user->title()->save($title);`

Comment: Returns the error: MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 449:
title

Comment: That's fine! you should allow mass assignment in `Model`. check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment and add fields like `title` in `protected $fillable = ['title'];`

Comment: yeah that worked thanks. need to spend more time going over tutorials. Also although it save the related record correclty I did get this error when it redirected me which wasn't happening before:  ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 418:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /var/www/test_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 63 and defined

Comment: Going to update as answer, as it might help others .It seems you `login` newly created user and not passing required argument. Share code it might help

Comment: forgot to return $user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, allow mass assignment you can check here [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) and add fields like title in `protected $fillable = ['title'];`

Then use as below:

```
 protected function create(array $data) { 
     $user = User::create([ 'name' => $data['name'], 'email' => $data['email'], 'password' => bcrypt($data['password']), ]); 
     $title = new Title(['title' => $data['title']]); $user->title()->save($title); 
     return $user; 
}
```

Comment: I ended up changing the create function in the AuthController to look like this: protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        
        $title = new Title(['title' => $data['title']]);
        $user->title()->save($title);

        return $user;
    }